# Compute the mean of product of two random variables by Monte Carlo methods

Tags: r, montecarlo

Let X<sub>1</sub>,...,X<sub>n</sub> be i.i.d normal distributions N(mu, sigma<sup>2</sup>). Let Y<sub>i</sub>=(X<sub>i</sub>-mu)(1-Phi((mu-X<sub>i</sub>)/sigma), i=1,...,n, where Phi is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.
I tried to compute the mean E(Y<sub>i</sub>.|X<sub>i</sub>-X<sub>j</sub>|) of product of Y<sub>i</sub> and |X<sub>i</sub>-X<sub>j</sub>| using R as follows. The code is for the case i=1, j=2.

```
mean.pro=function(n, mu, sigma){   
X=rnorm(n,mean=mu,sd=sigma)
ab=abs(X[1]-X[2])   
Y=(X-mu)*(1-pnorm((mu-X)/sigma,mean=mu,sd=sigma))
mean1=mean(ab*Y[1])   
return(mean1) 
}
```

But I didn't get the correct answer.
How can I use Monte Carlo method to compute that expected value?
Could you please help me fix the code or give me a hint how I can fix that?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you include what the correct answer is so that possible solutions can be tested and verified? It seems odd to fix the values of `i` and `j` and just get the mean for those two values. Are you sure that's what the question wants? It would seem that you are supposed to get the mean over all `i,,j` values. But it's currently not clear how `i` and `j` related to each other.